# If I want to fetch APIs not from only localhost but with different paths,as it changes as the user changes in a deployed NEXTJS app, what should I do?

Tags: api, deployment, next.js, host, vercel

I am working on a project and I have implemented register, login and logout functionalities. I am fetching user's data from a API and do the authentication. Problem is that I am able to fetch the API from localhost but not with other networks. For example, I can fetch user's details from `http://localhost:3000/api/signup` but not from `http://192.168.1.8:3000/api/signup`. For these custom domains I have a environment variable called NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST and I don't know if after deploying I can fetch the details. So what should I have to change here? My aim is that user can register from my "Deployed" website (On vercel) and can log in too. And I am using mongoose as database to store all the user's info.

Here is all the necessary code:

```
register.js

const data = {
        name,
        password,
        age,
        email,
        gender,
        income,
        marital,
        cast,
        education,
      };

      let res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST}/api/signup`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });
      let response = await res.json();


login.js

const data = {
        email,
        password,
      };

let res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST}/api/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });
      let response = await res.json();


api/signup.js

import User from "../../models/User";
import dbconnection from "../../middleware/mongoose";
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";

async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method == "POST") {
    const { name, email, gender, income, age, marital, cast, education } =
      req.body;

    let u = new User({
      name,
      email,
      gender,
      income,
      age,
      marital,
      cast,
      education,
      password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
        req.body.password,
        "thehehesecret"
      ).toString(),
    });
    await u.save();
    res.status(200).json({ success: "Yay" });
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid" });
  }
}

export default dbconnection(handler);

api/login.js

import User from "../../models/User";
import dbconnection from "../../middleware/mongoose";
import CryptoJs from "crypto-js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method == "POST") {
    console.log(req.body);
    let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) {
      const bytes = CryptoJs.AES.decrypt(user.password, "thehehesecret");
      const decPass = bytes.toString(CryptoJs.enc.Utf8);
      if (req.body.email == user.email && req.body.password == decPass) {
        var token = jwt.sign({ email: user.email }, "thehehejwt", {
          expiresIn: "1d",
        });
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, token });
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({ success: false, error: "Invalid credentials" });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: "No user found" });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: "Not a POST method" });
  }
}

export default dbconnection(handler);
```

.env file contains, MONGO_URI and NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST by default setted as http://localhost:3000

Comment: Where are you making the requests to the API routes from, client-side or server-side? If from the client-side, then you can just use a relative link e.g. `/api/signup`. If from the server-side (`getServerSideProps`) then you should use the logic from the API routes directly rather than making a request.

Comment: Well I have my mongodb database in AWS. So yes all the requests and responses are client side I guess? And I'm already using the relative link to fetch the data. Although I have solved this issue and will answer my own question in a while .. thank you :D